# How to retrieve data from two tables with certain conditions using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a two tables called **1.ReportTableDetails and 2.SecurityDetails**

**ReportTableDetails**

```
ReportName   | ColumnNames | FilterNames
--------------------------------------
Total Sales  | data1,data2 | data1,data2
Branch Sales | data1,data2 | data1,data2
```

**SecurityDetails**

```
SecurityLevel | ReportName   | RColumn     | RFilter
--------------------------------------------------------
     1        | Total Sales  | data1,data2 | data1,data2
     4        | Total Sales  | data1,data2 | data1,data2
```

> I will search the records by `SecurityLevel from SecurityDetails`. The condition is, if the **ReportName** is not found in **SecurityDetails**, it should pick the data from **ReportTableDetails**

**Expecting output**

```
SecurityLevel | ReportName   | RColumnNames| RFilterNames | ColumnNames | FilterNames
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1        | Total Sales  | data1,data2 | data1,data2  |             |
     1        | Branch Sales |             |              | data1,data2 | data1,data2
```

What I tried is inner join with SecurityDetails table. it retrieves when the report names are equal. But i want to retrieve which is not in **SecurityDetails** table also

Comment: A combination of outer join and isNull() should work.

Comment: @DanBracuk can you show me some sample code?

Comment: @mohamedfaisal I answered but I have some question with our output I mentione din my answer that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `left join`:

```
declare @SecurityLevel int = 1;
select 
      SecurityLevel = isnull(sd.SecurityLevel,@SecurityLevel)
    , ReportName    = isnull(sd.ReportName, rd.ReportName)
    , RColumnNames  = isnull(sd.RColumn,'')
    , RFilterNames  = isnull(sd.RFilter,'')
    , ColumnNames   = case when sd.RColumn is null 
                        then rd.ColumnNames else '' end
    , FilterNames   = case when sd.RFilter is null 
                        then rd.FilterNames else '' end
from ReportTableDetails as rd
  left join SecurityDetails as sd
    on sd.ReportName = rd.ReportName
      and sd.SecurityLevel = @SecurityLevel
```

returns:

```
+-------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
|SecurityLevel|  ReportName   | RColumnNames | RFilterNames | ColumnNames  | FilterNames |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
|           1 | Total Sales   | data1,data2  | data1,data2  |              |             |
|           1 | Branch Sales  |              |              | data1,data2  | data1,data2 |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

test setup: http://rextester.com/QGZHLO98381

```
create table ReportTableDetails (
    ReportName  varchar(64)
  , ColumnNames varchar(64)
  , FilterNames varchar(64)
  );
insert into ReportTableDetails values
    ('Total Sales  ','data1,data2 ','data1,data2')
  , ('Branch Sales ','data1,data2 ','data1,data2');
create table SecurityDetails (
    SecurityLevel int
  , ReportName    varchar(64)
  , RColumn       varchar(64)
  , RFilter       varchar(64)
  );
insert into SecurityDetails values
    (1 ,'Total Sales  ','data1,data2 ','data1,data2')
  , (4 ,'Total Sales  ','data1,data2 ','data1,data2');
/* ---------------------------------------------------*/
declare @SecurityLevel int = 1;
select 
      SecurityLevel = isnull(sd.SecurityLevel,@SecurityLevel)
    , ReportName    = isnull(sd.ReportName, rd.ReportName)
    , RColumnNames  = isnull(sd.RColumn,'')
    , RFilterNames  = isnull(sd.RFilter,'')
    , ColumnNames   = case when sd.RColumn is null 
                        then rd.ColumnNames else '' end
    , FilterNames   = case when sd.RFilter is null 
                        then rd.FilterNames else '' end
from ReportTableDetails as rd
  left join SecurityDetails as sd
    on sd.ReportName = rd.ReportName
      and sd.SecurityLevel = @SecurityLevel
```

Comment: Actually when i execute your query, it's retrieving only one row, which is equal the report name from both table

Comment: @mohamedfaisal Then you probably changed the query to use `where sd.SecurityLevel = @SecurityLevel` instead of leaving it as a join condition. Check the rextester link, it proves the query works for the provided test data. http://rextester.com/QGZHLO98381

Comment: sorry. its working fine. But i don't want the columname and filternames values of first row record

Comment: @mohamedfaisal Updated to return empty strings when `SecurityDetails` has column and filter values.

Answer (score 0):

This is compicated, because you want the security level even when there is no match.

I think the following does what you want:

```
select sl.SecurityLevel, rd.ReportName,
       sd.RColumnNames, sd.RFilterNames,
       (case when sd.SecurityLevel then rd.columnNames end) as columnMames,
       (case when sd.SecurityLevel then rd.FilterNames end) as FilterNames
from (select distinct sd.SecurityLevel from SecurityDetails sd where  sd.SecurityLevel = 1) sl cross join
     reportdetails rd left join                  
     on sd.ReportName = rd.ReportName and
        sd.SecurityLevel = sl.SecurityLevel;
```

The `sl` subquery looks strange (it returns only one row).  But this is generalizable to more security levels.